# Unable to append to next line in a file through beanshell assertion sampler in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

Have 2 steps in my JMeter script. Login and Second getting the orders, inside the login thread group I am using a bean shell assertion to validating few conditions and once I hit with an error I am writing the error to a log file. So for the first thread, it is writing it correctly but when it reaches the next assertion it overwrites the same file without appending it.

**First Assertion:**

```
import org.apache.jmeter.assertions.AssertionResult;
String failureMessage = "";
String successMessage = "";
String ResCode =SampleResult.getResponseDataAsString();
if (!ResCode.contains("Admin") )
    {
    failureMessage = "Got Response Code" + ResCode;
    log.warn("Creation of a new record failed: Response code " + ResCode);
    AssertionResult result = new AssertionResult("Expected Response 200");
    result.setFailure(true);
    result.setFailureMessage(failureMessage);
    prev.addAssertionResult(result);
    prev.setSuccessful(false);
    SampleResult.setStartNextThreadLoop(true);
    }
else {
    successMessage = "Got Response Code" + ResCode;
    log.info("----->"+successMessage);
    FileOutputStream logfile = new FileOutputStream(vars.get("LogFile"));
    PrintStream printtoFile = new PrintStream(logfile); 
    printtoFile.println( successMessage );
    printtoFile.close();
    logfile.close();
    }
```

**Second Assertion:**

```
import org.apache.jmeter.assertions.AssertionResult;
String failureOrderMessage = "";
String successOrderMessage = "";
OrderId = vars.get("workOrderId");
log.info("----->"+OrderId);

if (OrderId == null){
    failureOrderMessage = "The Order Id :"+OrderId;
    log.info("----->"+failureOrderMessage);
    FileOutputStream logfile = new FileOutputStream(vars.get("LogFile"));
    PrintStream printtoFile = new PrintStream(logfile); 
    printtoFile.println( failureOrderMessage );
    printtoFile.close();
    logfile.close();
}
else {
    successOrderMessage = "Getting few order id";
    log.info("----->"+successOrderMessage);
 }
```

The above assertion is working fine, but every time its overwrite the log file but I want to append it. 
Second

```
FileOutputStream logfile = new FileOutputStream(vars.get("LogFile"));
PrintStream printtoFile = new PrintStream(logfile); 
printtoFile.println( successMessage );
printtoFile.close();
logfile.close();
```

Do I need to every time declare the above code snippet to write to the log file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create [FileOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.io.File,%20boolean)) with append flag:

```
 FileOutputStream logfile = new FileOutputStream(vars.get("LogFile"), true);
```

> append - if true, then bytes will be written to the end of the file rather than the beginning

Comment: It worked, one more this do I need to declare
`PrintStream printtoFile = new PrintStream(logfile); 
printtoFile.println( successMessage );
printtoFile.close();
logfile.close();`
everytime I need to write to the file, is there a way I can declare once and call this methode ?